# What kind of antennas does a modern AESA (e.g. AN/APG-81) use?

Tags: antenna, radar

The AN/APG-81 has been used on F-35 airplanes. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/APG-81) give some details about it, including its predecessor and successor. From the image on Wikipedia page, and that for the predecessor AN/APG-77, I can't guess the type of antenna used on the individual TR modules or even identify individual modules. The array seems to be a thick horizontal strip with slits cut regularly.

What type of antenna do the individual TR modules use? It doesn't seem to be a [simple dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_radar), a patch antenna  or a [waveguide slot antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/APG-63_radar_family) from the pictures.

Answer (score 1):

If you look close at the picture in the WiKi article you referenced, you can see that it's a notch radiator.

Comment: Thanks, why do the antennas seem to be a single horizontal strip, rather than individual notch radiators connected to individual TR modules?

Comment: Horizontal strip - do you mean like slotted waveguide?

Comment: If you look close at that picture of the AN/APG-77 (F-22 radar antenna), you can see that it too is made up of notch radiators.  The differences between the F-35 & F-22 antennas are due to different manufacturing techniques.  You have to keep in mind that those two systems were designs 20 years apart, and a lot of the differences are due to manufacturing techniques and improvements.

Comment: @pakieng it's way more cost effective to separate the aperture and TR modules on large systems like this.